# How to send a MYSQL resultset object recieved by the servlet to a jsp page?

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets

I  have  accessed a MYSQL data base and retrieved a result set in the servlet. how do i send the result set to the jsp page and read the different fields from the result set

ex:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

Connection con = DBCon.getConnection(DBType.MYSQL);

PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(query);
ResultSet data =statement.executeQuery();
request.setAttribute("data", data);

while(data.next()){
    System.out.println("ID:" + data.getObject("id")+"  Username: " + data.getObject("saltedkey") + "  EmailId" + data.getObject("email"));

    //this works well in the system console. Now i wd like to send the ResultSet data to jsp.. how do i do that.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We should not send the result set object to the JSP. Instead, copy the values into a model, close the result set and connection and set the model into request scope. On the JSP, simply iterate the model.

Comment: hi adashr.. im pretty new// how do i do that.. example my resultset data has four fields id username saltedkey email. how do i do that.it wd be so helpfu;l show an example please

Comment: If you read any basic documentation on how to use JDBC in a JSP Servlet project, you'll know

Comment: D u mean to say ,i shd create a method.. in a class which reads this object and returns it as variables when i access from a jsp